# C# MVC 4 wkhtmltopdf - Sharing session same application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, session, wkhtmltopdf

I have my MVC4 web-application which is generating some reports and stores those data in the users session.

After previewing the data, the user can export the report to pdf by using `wkhtmltopdf`. 
My problem is, that the session-data is not present when the `wkhtmltopdf.exe` is accessing the website (url given by application).

I tried to pass the `SessionID` with `HttpContext.Current.Session.SessionID` as `get`-Parameter and retrieve the session-data inside the action (now called by `wkhtml`) as follows:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(sessionKey))
{
    var sessionManager = new SessionIDManager();

    bool redirect;
    bool isAdded;

    sessionManager.SaveSessionID(HttpContext.ApplicationInstance.Context, sessionKey, out redirect, out isAdded);
}
```

but my session is always `null`.

I already searched around but could not find anything helpful about how to share session-data inside the same application when `SessionID` is known by the application.

Comment: instead of sharing session data between sessions, why don't you use Application?

Comment: @Ewan because of this would mean chaning the code on several different parts. I thought there is a "simpler" solution instead of storing data in Application.

Comment: @Ewan: Re-Thought your answer. It's correct. I will store it in the Application before the wkhtmltopdf-call and remove it afterwards. Thanks